# how to implement react component in angular project?

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs

i'm trying to implement react component in angular project.
but it doesn't work.

i have js file(react component) and want to use in angular.
for example,

1. react file...

`import React from "react";`

`const Test= () => {`
`return <div>hello</div>`
`}`
`export default Test`

and want to use in angular project.

2. angular html file..

`<Test/>`

i've search and found out 'reactDom.render()'. but never works. 
i need full code of example.
does anyone help me to resolve this?

```
enter code here
```

Comment: I cannot imagine why would you use react components in an Angular app, but here's a quick description: https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/docs/4.1.1/ht_use_react_component_in_angular_2.x.html. And an other one: https://medium.com/@zacky_14189/embedding-react-components-in-angular-the-easy-way-60f796b68aef

Comment: thanks. we have angular project which is already finished. and try to add function with react (developers use each different js lib, so decide to use react). and we will reuse angular project.

Comment: @Hunor there is absolutely a certain need to mount a react app inside ANY web app, especially during migration projects

Comment: @andymccullough aka "how to shoot myself in the foot a few months from now" react within angular or vise versa is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Never said it was easy, and agreed that it depends on the strategic direction of the app - i.e. it shouldn't be a decision to continue with angular AND react - but there is definitely a need for it when it comes to migration projects from Angular TO React, because let's face it, Angular is awful...  If the interfaces are kept clean between the apps and the responsibilities of each of the apps are well defined, there shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that you need to use `ReactDOM.render()`.

There is an article here https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/docs/4.1.1/ht_use_react_component_in_angular_2.x.html amongst others on the web that will show you roughly how to use it within an angular app.  It also outlines how you would pass data, as props, from your Angular app, to the React app.

Basically you will use `ReactDOM.render(x, y)` to mount your react app, `x` onto a dom node, `y`